# Check who made changes in server

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

We have a digital ocean server which runs 5-6 wordpress websites we have. We have 3 programmers who have access to the server. And today all websites were down until I fixed. I didn't know this issue until one programmer told me.

I checked the log and found out:

`unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed`

I saw this

`Failed to restart php7.0-fpm.service: Unit php7.0-fpm.service is masked.`

When I tried to restart it.

I checked the file and nothing was in that directory, so I install, then restarted the server, websites were back online.

My question is: is there any way to find out who did this? Or when it happened? Any helps will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In general, I never give command line (terminal) access to my programmers. At max, they can upload/download code files using sftp

Comment: On ubuntu servers, you can check `/var/log/auth.log` - it will give you an idea of who logged in and at what time. maybe you can connect some dots there, based on the timestamps in the php-fpm log etc

Comment: check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127432/logging-ssh-access-attempts

Comment: Yes, I know that's how it should be handle in general. But my company is tricky, they all have access to this server because we are working on different projects on the same server in the past. And the owner of the company wants at least 2 people have access to the server.

Comment: Thanks, @MadhurBhaiya let me check that out

Comment: I checked the website config files, location ~ \.php$ { fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; // file is missing here for 2 months } The server runs without problem until yesterday, showing 502 bad gateway, and unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed

Comment: It is quite likely that `php7.0-fpm.sock` file is read once (when the server starts) and it does not need it afterwards, while the server is running. So only when you try to restart it, you shall get this issue, because then it tries to read the sock file again

Comment: I remember I restarted nginx last week without problem, do you think is that possible that cache expired cause the problem?

Comment: No I dont think so. Was there any upgrade/update done to the server, especially these packages ?

Comment: I'm not sure, since 3 of us have root access to the server, I couldn't find much from  the /var/log/auth.log

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like nginx crashed and had to be restarted.
It's something that happens every now and again on our servers and restarting the server always gets it back online.
In this case, I don't believe that you should point the finger at anyone as sometimes these things just happen with servers.
It might be worth checking over the server for any potential issues like the disk space, etc.
Keep an eye on the error log and see if that provides any clues.

Comment: Thank you, I restarted nginx right after I noticed the website went down, but nothing changed. But I will keep looking any possible reasons that cause the /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock missing

Comment: I checked the website config files, 
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; // file is missing here for 2 months
    }
The server runs without problem until yesterday, showing 502 bad gateway, and unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed